# Redirecting libpng warnings C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program in c++ using libpng, it just compares images and does stuff with it, my problem is that libpng sometimes shows a warning (libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile), I know how to solve it using ImageMagick library and an external script, what I want to know is if a) Can I redirect that warning? I tried redirecting cout, clog and cerr but the message still prints (I tested it and it blocks any other print I try), and b) Is there a way correct the warning using Opencv2 and c++?

EDIT:
After looking at png_set_error_fn() and finding out there's no way for me to use it with opencv2, I looked for the buffer that uses libpng to print errors and warnings, it uses stderr and redirected it using:

```
    const char* nullStream = "/dev/null";
    #ifdef "WIN32"
    nullStream = "nul:";
    #endif
    freopen(nullStream,"w",stderr);
```

Comment: The source code to libpng is freely available. Have you tried searching this library's source code for that error message, then seeing if the code provides some way to suppress it?

Comment: No I didn't know that, I will take a look, I till hope someone has an answer faster than me

Comment: In the past I also had some questions about something that a particular library was doing. Not exactly this, but usually something else that was not documented very well. I always found it much more productive to investigate the library's source code myself, and have the answer maybe, at most, in an hour or two, than to post a question to some web site or a discussion forum, and wait a day or so for someone to reply.

Comment: https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng12.png.set.error.fn.1.html

Comment: I'm looking at that library and others mr. n. 'pronouns' m, but I can't seem to find how to use it

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google, seems like libpng supports redirection of errors and warnings into your own callback, `png_set_error_fn` is the setter you are looking for.

Comment: That is not working, opencv2 is not allowing me to access the png_ptr needed by png_set_error_fn